# callback issue in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I am facing call back problem when calling a service function

Here is my function defined in `registrationService`

```
function hasUserAccessToLevel(incentiveLevel, callback, showRegistrationView) {

            var url = "...";
            httpWrapperService.get(url)
                .then(
                function success(data) {
                    var hasAccess = incentiveLevel <= data.Level;
                    callback(hasAccess);
                    if (showRegistrationView && hasAccess == false) {
                        showRegistrationViewForLevel(incentiveLevel);
                    }
                },
                function error(errorObject) {

                    alert("User has not access\r\nTODO : show popup for registration/login");
                }

            );
            return false;
        }
```

and In my directive I am using this function as

```
function checkAuthentication() {
                registrationService.hasUserAccessToLevel(2, function (hasAccess) {
                    if (hasAccess == false){
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }




function loadDocuments() {
                var target=checkAuthentication()
                if(target)
                {
                  //load both private and public
                }
                else
                {
                  // load only public
                }

            }
```

Now the problem I am facing is , I have another function `loaDocuments` , when user is logged in it should come inside `if(target)` block, but when I am debuggin the function it is saying target is undefined and hence the control is going to else part , which is wrong. I know that there is some callback issue but dont know how to rectify it.

Any help is appriciable.
Thanks

Comment: `checkAuthentication` method is not returning anything so return value will be always `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You shall use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service. `checkAuthentication()` return `undefined` because `hasUserAccessToLevel()` is asynchronys and at the time of call hasn't return value. The solution is to return `promise` object.

You code can be written like this:

```
function checkAuthentication() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    registrationService.hasUserAccessToLevel(2, function (hasAccess) {
        defer.resolve(hasAccess);
    }, function () {
        defer.reject();
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

function loadDocuments() {
    checkAuthentication().then(function (target) {
        if (target) {
            //load both private and public
        }
        else {
           // load only public
        }
    });
}
```